# Don't have Oracle folder in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE

Tags: oracle

I'm installing Oracle 11g R2 and when I log in in SQL PLUS, It have error ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error, and I think because I don't have Oracle folder in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE, how to create Oracle folder

Comment: Add `TNS_ADMIN` parameter to Environment variables with the path containing `TNSNAMES.ORA`

Comment: Most likely you installed the 32-bit version of Oracle. Check for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to a database locally on the computer, ensure that you have set ORACLE_SID environment variable:

```
SET ORACLE_SID=ORCL
SQLPLUS user/password
```